# How to align in HTML in forms

Tags: html, alignment

This is my code I'm using, can anyone tell me how can I align my caterer and the dropdown menu. I got 5 screens some of them I manage to align but in this screen, I have no idea of how to do it.

[image]

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="card m-b-30">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="card-title">RESERVATION COMPLETION</h5>
            </div>


            <div class="card-body">
                <form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" id="Id" />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Category">Caterer</label>
                                <select class="form-control js-example-basic-single" id="data-packagetypes-caterercombo" style="width:200px;">
                                    <option value="">Golden Crown</option>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="ReservationNo">Reservation No</label>
                                <select class="form-control js-example-basic-single" id="data-reservationcompletion-combo" style="width:200px;" required>
                                    <option value="">--Select--</option>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-dark">Complete Reservation</button>
                    <button type="reset" id="btnClear" class="btn btn-dark">Clear</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and how do you wanna align that?

Comment: @IgorGrange I need to shift a little bit to the right ( caterer and the dropdown menu)

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your CSS. But I think you can add some paddings to your `card-body` element. Something like: ```.card-body { padding: 0 15px; }```. Or maybe bootstrap has some wrapper container for that

Answer (score 0):

In First Line Of code  div class="row ". you Can Add  **align="center"** Like This

```html
<div class="row " align="center">
```

[See Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3yCT.png)